# Is it possible to "group" template special case?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, std-pair

For example, I have a template function used to iterate vector in vector:

```
template<class T>
void test(T t){
    for(auto tt : t){
        test(tt);
    }
}
```

which has pair as special case, which the pair type may be double,float,int,string,...:

```
pair<double,double>
pair<double,float>
pair<double,int>
pair<double,string>
pair<float,double>
pair<float,float>
pair<float,int>
pair<float,string>
pair<int,double>
pair<int,float>
pair<int,int>
pair<int,string>
pair<string,double>
pair<string,float>
pair<string,int>
pair<string,string>
```

the template may do some work which pair.first is independent of pair.second (may be add element to json,write to file,... now use printf to represent):

```
template<>
void test(pair<double,double> p){
    printf("%f,",p.first);
    printf("%f\n",p.second);
}

template<>
void test(pair<double,float> p){
    printf("%f,",p.first);
    printf("%f\n",p.second);
}
.
.
.
```

the code works,but the number of template function is horrible because it needs 16 templates, is it possible to separate and group template special case as first and second so that it needs 8 templates only like this:

```
pair<double,T>
pair<float,T>
pair<int,T>
pair<string,T>
pair<T,double>
pair<T,float>
pair<T,int>
pair<T,string>
```

I try the following but cannot compile:

```
template<class SECOND>
void test(pair<double,SECOND> p){
    printf("%f,",p.first);
    test<double,SECOND>(p);
}

template<class SECOND>
void test(pair<float,SECOND> p){
    printf("%f,",p.first);
    test<double,SECOND>(p);
}
.
.
.
template<class FIRST>
void test(pair<FIRST,int> p){
    printf("%d\n",p.second);
}

template<class FIRST>
void test(pair<FIRST,string> p){
    printf("%s\n",p.second.c_str());
}
```

is it possible to rewrite the template like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace details {
    template<class T>
    using is_wanted_type =
             std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<int, T>{}
                                       || std::is_same<float, T>{}
                                       || std::is_same<double, T>{} 
                                       || std::is_same<std::string, T>{}>;

    void process_first(int) { /* ... */ }
    void process_first(float) { /* ... */ }
    void process_first(double) { /* ... */ }
    void process_first(const std::string &) { /* ... */ }

    void process_second(int) { /* ... */ }
    void process_second(float) { /* ... */ }
    void process_second(double) { /* ... */ }
    void process_second(const std::string &) { /* ... */ }
}

template<class T1, class T2>
std::enable_if_t<details::is_wanted_type<T1>{} && details::is_wanted_type<T2>{}>
test(const std::pair<T1, T2> &p) {
    details::process_first(p.first);
    details::process_second(p.second);
}
```